# Best way to pass single data string from an action to a component React/Redux/ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a string in my action that I want to set as text for a notification box in my component. I am having trouble figuring out how to move that string to the component using react/redux/ES6.

I have a reducer

```
`export default function changeNotificationText(state = initialState.notifyMessage, action, newMessage) {

let newState;
switch(action.type){
    case types.DELETE_PROCESS_NOTIF_MESSAGE:
     state = newMessage;
      return state;
    case types.DELETE_PROCESS_NOTIF_MESSAGE_FAILURE:
      state = newMessage;
      return state;
 }
 return state;



 }
```

`

The state item is called notifyMessage.

Here is the call to the reducer from the action

```
export function changeNotificationTextSuccess(newMessage) {

return {type: types.DELETE_PROCESS_NOTIF_MESSAGE,  notifyMessage: newMessage};
```

}

Comment: What you have so far? You need to dispatch the action, have a reducer to catch the action and set the state, you have to use that state in your component. What is the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: Do you want a complete tutorial? Or do you need help with a clear problem?

Comment: I have updated my question. I am having trouble updating the state from the reducer. I have copied my action call and the reducer. I just want to update a single item in the state notifyMessage. The component already reads from the state correctly just can't change the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your reducer should look like this:

```
export default function changeNotificationText(state = initialState.notifyMessage, { type, notifyMessage }) {
    switch(type){
        case types.DELETE_PROCESS_NOTIF_MESSAGE:
            return notifyMessage;
        case types.DELETE_PROCESS_NOTIF_MESSAGE_FAILURE:
            return notifyMessage;
    }
    return state;
}
```

notice that `notifyMessage` is part of the action you dispatch

Comment: the notify message is still coming in undefined to the reducer.

Comment: does the action you're dispatching has a `notifyMessage` property like in the example you showed?

Comment: Did you try `dispatch(changeNotificationTextSuccess('some text')) ` ?

Comment: Yes but a string variable called notifyString

Comment: dispatch(changeNotificationTextSuccess('test string')); this is my action call